# Moodle applicable_formats for quiz attempt pages

Tags: block, visibility, moodle

**How can I create and set a block to show on all quiz attempt pages?**

I have the following code in a custom Moodle block:

```
public function applicable_formats() {
    return array(
        'all'   => true,
    );
}
```

My objective is to display my block on all course quiz attempt pages such as: **http://www.mymoodle.com/mod/quiz/attempt.php?attempt=61**

However the options only allow for setting on the current quiz.

All the other quiz pages don't show my block.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work as adminstrator on the site itself by changing some settings:

Turn block editing on.

Go under "configure [yourblock]".

Now the configuration page of you block appears.

Under the tab "Where this block appears":

Choose in "Display on page types" the configuration that is right for you. For example choose "Any Quiz module Page".

Save.

That's it. :-)